# nextjs & @react-three/drei - TypeError: Failed to parse URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, 3d, gltf, react-three-drei

I'm building a `nextjs` app with 3D animations using `@react-three/drei`.

I have a `gltf` file in the `public` folder, under the `desktop_pc` folder called `scene. gltf`.

The path from the project root is: `/public/desktop_pc/scene.gltf`.

When importing the `gltf` file into the `useGLTF` hook, I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /desktop_pc/scene.gltf
```

[Github Repository - nextjs & @react-three/drei - TypeError: Failed to parse URL](https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/tree/invalid-url-error)

This is the component code:

```
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import React from "react";

const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF("/desktop_pc/scene.gltf");
  return <div>Computers</div>;
};

export default Computers;
```

These are my attempts so far (The links leads to the GitHub solution of them):

1. Dynamic import - https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/tree/invalid-url-error-dynamic-solution
2. Lazy import - https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/tree/invalid-url-error-lazy-solution
3. Installing the `Three` & `three-stdlib` npm packages.
4. Specify the exact path from the component to the file location.
5. Adding a dot at the start of the path string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

1. Download `three` and `react-three-fiber` packages.
2. Use the `@react-three/fiber` hook: `useLoader`.

- **NOT `useGLTF` from `@react-three/drei`**

3. Wrap the `GLTF` model component with a `Canvas` component.

```
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";

const Computers = ({ isMobile = false }) => {
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "/desktop_pc/scene.gltf");

  return (
    <group>
      <primitive
        scale={isMobile ? 0.7 : 0.75}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
        object={gltf.scene}
      />
    </group>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Computers />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

4. Use as any other component

```
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <section className={`relative w-full h-screen mx-auto`}
      <ComputersCanvas />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
}
```

**GitHub Links**:

1. [First working commit](https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/pull/2/commits/61978f69d52bf32e5bbbb47d048e14e393d689d3)
2. [Full PR](https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/pull/2)

Comment: still same error in `build` with `output: "export",`